# How to apply custom fonts to Communication Sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding, modern-experience, composed-looks, communication-site

How can we apply custom fonts to Communications Sites (and other of the new emerging site types)?

According to [this overview](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/SharePoint-site-branding-and-page-customization-solutions.md) we would have to apply a **composed look**. But this composed look is bound to a master page. Furthermore the theming engine is called "SharePoint 2013 Theming Engine" which sounds like this is old stuff.

Is this ok to use composed looks in a modern context to change the fonts? If not: what are the alternatives in a modern context?

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous customizations which currently are not supported for "modern" pages:

-> **Adding "classic" web parts** on "modern" pages

-> **Custom CSS** via AlternateCSSUrl web property

-> **Custom JavaScript** embedded via User Custom Actions - See note on SharePoint Framework Extensions

-> **Custom master pages** - More extensive branding will be supported later using alternative options

More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)

On the Upside:

-> SPFx Web parts are responsive.

Also you may try a little custom themes if that works for you. See the Webcast recently out [here](https://dev.office.com/blogs/custom-themes-with-modern-sharepoint-sites)

**Note**: The blog you have shared is meant for classic experience.

Comment: Unfortunately composed looks are not explicitly mentioned in the list of supported and unsupported means.